# Stop PostBack in a MenuItem click but the event should execute

Tags: c#, asp.net

In my website I added `menu` control and when one `MenuItem` is clicked the data loads to the `GridView` but the page reloads again and it comes to top. When I click on `MenuItem` the data should load and also the page should not refresh.(i.e the page should not do a `PostBack` while the data loads in a `GridView`)

```
<asp:Menu ID="Menu1" OnMenuItemClick="Menu1_MenuItemClick"  CssClass="portfolio-item" EnableViewState="true" runat="server" Orientation="Horizontal" >
    <Items>
        <asp:MenuItem Text="Items" Value="Items" Selectable="false" >
            <asp:MenuItem Text="item1" Value="item1" Selectable="false" >
                <asp:MenuItem Text="item2"  Value="item2" ></asp:MenuItem>
                <asp:MenuItem Text="item3 Value="item3" ></asp:MenuItem>
            </asp:MenuItem>
            <asp:MenuItem Text="qwerty" Value="qwerty" Selectable="false">
                <asp:MenuItem Text="MenuSub" Value="MenuSub"></asp:MenuItem>
            </asp:MenuItem>
        </asp:MenuItem>
    </Items>
</asp:Menu>
```

It should not refresh when the data loads in a `MenuItem` click.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the [`MaintainScrollPositionOnPostback`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.maintainscrollpositiononpostback(v=vs.110).aspx) to `True` to prevent your page comes to top and return the user to the same position in the client browser after `postback`. Like this:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MaintainScrollPositionOnPostback="True" ... %>
```